# Using Boolean expressions as arguments on Xtext

Tags: boolean, arguments, expression, xtext

I'm trying to create a grammar on Xtext that allows to pass a Boolean expression as an argument to another special function that gets **only** Boolean parameters (implicitly, without declaring it's a Boolean type).

For example:

```
someFunction(...){
   foo(4>3, a==b)
}

foo(arg1,arg2)
{
   //do something with arg1 and arg2
}
```

Do you have a simple example that demonstrates how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not quite clear what your actual problem is.

If this is about building a grammar for expression: use this as starting point

```
Expression:
    OrExpression
;   

OrExpression returns Expression:
    AndExpression ({OrExpression.left=current} "||" right=AndExpression)*  
;   

AndExpression returns Expression:
    ComparisonExpression ({AndExpression.left=current} "&&" right=ComparisonExpression)*  
;

ComparisonExpression returns Expression:
    PrimaryExpression ({ComparisonExpression.left=current} operator=("<"|"<="|"=="|">="|">") right=PrimaryExpression)*
;

PrimaryExpression returns Expression:
    "(" Expression ")"
    | Literal
;

Literal returns Expression:
    {Literal} value="true" | "false" | INT
;
```

see for some insights https://typefox.io/parsing-expressions-with-xtext

if this is about building a typesystem have a look at http://xsemantics.sourceforge.net/